# Cefsharp Chrominumwebbrowser not working in WPF

Tags: wpf, chromium-embedded, cefsharp

Hi I am new to cefsharp and tried using Cefsharp chromium web browser .
when ever i tried to call the webbrowser it throws an exception like below

> Could not load file or assembly 'CefSharp.Wpf, PublicKeyToken=40c4b6fc221f4138' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.'

[image]

But i have added the reference cefsharp.wpf in project
What do i miss here ?

And if i tried from codebehinf too the same issue occurs.

I just had the below piece of code next to InnitializeComponent.

```
ChromiumWebBrowser browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser();
```

Comment: Did you install CefSharp using Nuget?

Comment: You can test with https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample

Comment: Yes i installed cefsharp.wpf using nuget.

Comment: WPF designer support is tricky, you can always just add the control in code.

Comment: Yes i tried in code and there too am getting the same error

Comment: Try the minimal example. Are you targeting at least .net 4.5.2? Please post your relevant pieces of code

Comment: Updated the question

Comment: Try the Minimal Example

Comment: Thanks for the reply so far @amaitland . I tried the minimal example and itw working good .Will check it with my code :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manually i counldn't resolve the issue in my working solution.

As a work around what i did is as @amaitland suggested i cloned a copy of [CefSharp Minimal Example from here](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample) and used the Minimal Example for WPF solution.

I just copied all the logic from my solution tand pasted it in the minimal expansion and updated it .

Now ChromiumWebBrowser works fine for me ( Only after using that Minimal example provided by cefsharp )..

Answer (score 0):

In Application > Properties > Build
Change Check "Prefer 32-bits"